# How to configure two different Apache instances on the same port number with different IPs on single server

Tags: apache

Is it possible to configure two different Apache instances on the same port number with different IPs on a single server?
Both ports are configured for the same server.
httpd.conf of First Apache-

```
<VirtualHost 10.100.30.50:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example-80/pqr"
    ServerName www.example.org
</VirtualHost>
```

Below configuration is not allowing to start the second Apache instance.
httpd2.conf of second Apache-

```
<VirtualHost 10.100.30.40:80>
    DocumentRoot "/www/example-80/xyz"
    ServerName www.example.org
</VirtualHost>
```

Second instance is coming up with different IP apart from port 80.
Like- 10.100.30.40:8081

[getting this error while trying to start second apache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R0WS.png)

Comment: Sure, and looking at the IP addresses your example is taken from the [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/ip-based.html#multiple). Are you `Listen`ing on both IPs and ports? What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not configured the second IP in any interface on the server. Please configure the IP as virtual interface on the server and try to start apache.